# Using xargs to compile a list of Java files

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a directory tree with several java files. Example:

```
top
 |-- src1
 |    |--- folder A
 |    |--- folder B
 |-- src2
 |    |--- folder A
 |    |--- folder B
...
```

I want to compile all the files in those folders and move the compiled files to `folder A-bin`or `folder B-bin` accordingly in the respective `src` folder. I have read that I can do this with the `xargs` utility, but I can't make heads or tails from the manual entry.

Can some one point me a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you obliged to use xargs to compile these?

Why not take a look at java [Makefiles](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html)? 
They will make your life easier when building a project.

Also, one more advice, i recommend that you take look into [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Easy to use, and very handful when your java project get bigger in time. 
Here is a [quick guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to Maven.

Basic Makefile:

```
JC=javac
JR=java

build: ref.java
        $(JC) ref.java

run: ref.class
        $(JR) ref

clean:
        rm -f *.class
```

Another example: (taken from the guide above)

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        Foo.java \
        Blah.java \
        Library.java \
        Main.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
        $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am building a script to preform some tests and not to build the project. I have solved this anyway.

Comment: in case this helps, use xargs this way: cd my_project; find . -name "*.java" -type f | xargs javac; this will compile every *.java under my_project

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want to stick with bash + javac is to use find to identify the .java files, store the results in a variable, and then check if the variable was not empty.

```
SRC=`find src -name "*.java"`
if [ ! -z $SRC ]; then
    javac -classpath $CLASSPATH -d obj $SRC
    # stop if compilation fails
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit; fi
fi
```